How can I see a comprehensive departure schedule for a stop included in Maps transit directions?
When Google Maps returns transit directions they include the estimated departure time for each departure/transfer point, but they don't show the schedule for future departures of the same bus (or train, etc.) from the same stop.
For example, if the directions indicate a bus will depart in 5 minutes, it doesn't indicate when the next bus after that is scheduled to depart, or the one after that, and so on.
By contrast, in Google Maps for Android if, for example, you click on a particular bus departure/transfer point, Maps will display the upcoming departure schedule for that same bus, for that location, for the next hour or so.
Is there any way to display this information in the web app?

Google Maps doesn't support this. It used to be included in Maps in a feature called Schedule Explorer but Google retired it in 2022, and it hasn't been replaced.
Workarounds:

When Maps returns transit directions it includes a link (URL) to the transit operator that provided the data. Any operator sophisticated enough to feed schedule data to Google is likely to have dynamic schedules on their site and/or app.

As you noted, the mobile Map apps (Android/IOS) will give you the upcoming route schedule for a particular stop.




Scheduling data is provided to Maps by the transit operators according to the General Transit Feed Specification. See GTFS (Wikipedia)

A comprehensive transit schedule for each stop is not returned by the Routes API.

Dated, but likely still useful, SO post about the (older) Directions API: How to get public transport time schedule from The Google Maps Directions API

See the GitHub repository MobilityData/awesome-transit, which includes a Community list of transit APIs, apps, datasets, research, and software.



re "1.5"; Interesting. I get a big list instead, sometimes till the end of the day or more. Sometimes you can even click the rows to see the bus icon on-map.

Yes, I was just using my own mobile experience, which seems to be consistent, but I haven't done much testing to double-check. Don't know if the length of schedule provided is tied to the specific transit operator or something else. I was not sure, and that's why I included "ish,"as I  expected some variability, but based on what you have just reported, I will edit the answer as I don't know how to explain the difference.
